# textbox focus jumps to above dropdown list when clicked into

Tags: controls, textbox

Ive never seen this.

I click into my textbox to type in a value and as soon as i release the mouse button focus jumps to the above dropdown list. No javascript on these items.

If i hold the mouse button down i can type in a value to the textbox.

Any idea?

Comment: ok..happens in all browsers except IE 7.

Comment: can you provide more details?

Comment: I click in a textbox(asp.net) and i release the mouse it loses focus to the dropdownlist about the textbox. The cursor doesnt stay in the clicked textbox.

Comment: I looked at it through Firebug and didnt see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: its not unfortunately. I might be able to work it and get it online shortly.

Comment: Having the same problem in Win forms applicartion !! any answers ??

Comment: Anyone have a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my textbox inside the label tag by mistake - this was the reason the focus jumped for me

Answer (score 0):

Someone might be catching the mouseup event.

Event handling differs across browsers which might explain why it happens in all browsers except IE7.